# Behavior function not recognized

Tags: javascript

I want https://github.com/dynamick/multiple-filter-masonry to load the drupal way.
But I fail, here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.druckgott = {
  attach: function (context,settings) {


  var $container = $('.masonry-processed');

  //here browser tells me that the function multipleFilterMasonry is not
  //a function:

  $container.multipleFilterMasonry({
    itemSelector: '.challenge',
    filtersGroupSelector:'.filters'
  });

//here my editor tells me that multipleFilterMasonry is unused:
$(context).on(function multipleFilterMasonry(options){...});
... 

   });
   }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

So how can I load the function to be recognized by the browser???

-- Update: also doesn't work because of the lack of chaining! $container... --

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.druckgott = {
      attach: function (context,settings) {

  //console.log('This would be the main JS file.');
  $('.filters .btn input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });

  // initialize Masonry
  var $container = $('.masonry-processed');

  /*$container.multipleFilterMasonry({
    itemSelector: '.challenge',
    filtersGroupSelector:'.filters'
  });*/
  var options = {itemSelector: '.challenge',filtersGroupSelector:'.filters'};


     var cache=[];
     //the main job of the function is to cache the item,because we are going to filter the items later
     var init = function($container){
             console.log($container.find(options.itemSelector));
        $container.find(options.itemSelector).each(function(){

            cache.push($(this));
        });
        $container.masonry(options);
     }
     //filter items in cache
     var filterItems = function(selector){
        var result=[];
        $(cache).each(function(item){
            $(selector).each(function(index,sel) {
                if(cache[item].is(sel)){
                    if($.inArray(cache[item], result) === -1) result.push(cache[item]);
                }
            });
        })
        return result;
     }

     //reload masonry
     var reload = function($container,items){
        $container.empty();
        $(items).each(function(){
            $($container).append($(this));
        });
        $container.masonry('reloadItems');
        $container.masonry();
     }

     var proc = function($container){
        $(options.filtersGroupSelector).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).change(function(){
                var selector = [];
                $(options.filtersGroupSelector).find('input[type=checkbox]').each( function() {
                    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                        selector.push( '.' + $(this).val() );
                    }
                });
                var items = cache;
                if (selector.length > 0) {
                    items = filterItems(selector);
                }
                reload($container,items);
            })
        })
     }

     return $(this).each(function() { 
      //here it is usually only return this.each(function())...
        var $$ = $(this);
        init($$);
        proc($$);
     });
   }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Couple of questions...How are you loading the code above?  If it's in a .js file that you attached as a library (and defined in your module's .libraries.yml) then you are doing that part the Drupal way. Are the 2 js files from the github link loaded on your page?  (main.js and multipleFilterMasonry.js)  Here is [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) that discusses adding js files.

Comment: Sorry, this is drupal 7. No yml file ;) But: I added the js file per drupal_add_js(...) from my custom module and it is been loaded. Otherwise the browser couldn't say nothing. And it's one file included by the standard Drupal.behaviors approach.

Comment: And are the 2 masonry .js files also loaded the same way via drupal_add_js()?

Comment: Nope, via libraries by the masonry api module.

Comment: How are you attaching the masonry library to the page?

Comment: I really do not understand the question. the module as written does this, I can see the masonry is loaded. The masonry effect works. I rewrote the file, I update immediately, and the browser tells now that the masonry.pkgd.min.js cannot set position, which is clear because I cannot do chaining from $container right now.

Comment: Sorry I am not being very helpful.  Your code snippet seems to be an exact copy of the how to use sample at the github page.  Given that, then if those 2 masonry filter .js files and the masonry.js files are loaded, then I wouldn't think you should be getting that error.  So I assumed the issue had to do with the loading of the files.  Looks like it is something else though.

Comment: So the browser tells you that `multipleFilterMasonry` isn't a function, but it still manages to run the function anyway? I'm afraid I don't understand the problem, that's not something any JS engine I've used would do

Comment: Nope, the code wasn't running. I integrated the vars from the first function into the second. But because there is no chaining anymore from $container (the first part: $container.multipleFilterMasonry({...}) ) now masonry has no position (the second part return $(this) .. at the bottom.

Comment: Open your console, execute `jQuery.multipleFilterMasonry`. Is the result `undefined`? If yes, your assumption that a file defining that function is loaded in the current request is incorrect. If no, your script might be executing before Masonry is available. Please edit the question and update with those details once you've determined the status of the plugin

Comment: Actually that'll probably be `jQuery.fn.multipleFilterMasonry`

Comment: If I execute jQuery.fn.multipleFilterMasonry in console, the result ist not undefinded!

jQuery.fn.multipleFilterMasonry
function (options){
    var cache=[];
    var filters = [];

    if(options.selectorType === 'list') {
      $(options.filtersGroupSelector).children().each(function() {
        filters.push($(this).d…

Comment: So now add `console.log(jQuery.fn.multipleFilterMasonry);` to the top of your behavior's attach method. If you get `undefined`, it means your script is executing before the browser is aware of the plugin, and you need to adjust the weight. If you get the same result as dumping it straight from the console, you know the error is in your custom js somewhere

Comment: Cool! It is undefined!!! So how can I adjust a weight and where???

Comment: You can do it in PHP: `drupal_add_js($file, array('weight' => 999, 'group' => JS_THEME));`

Comment: Thanx a lot, it is called now! How can I give you any points, I saw you have definitve not enough ;)